# Improve accuracy of integer multiplication and division for exponential moving average

Tags: c++, c, math, integer

I need to smooth 16-bit values (ADC readings of an STM32 MCU). The used function needs to be fast and integer-math only (it's run in an interrupt handler). While an exponential moving average works great for getting rid of excess variance the absolute value is always off by some percent (and always downward).

The naive version code bit looks like this:

```
uint32_t ema = 0;
const unsigned factor = 8; // 2^factor overall smoothing
const unsigned m = (0b1u << factor) - 1u;
ema = (ema * m + adc[0]) >> factor;
```

For example one sensor value reads values in the 1700-1704 range, but in above version the `ema` value stabilizes at around 1690 using factor 8 and 1650 for factor 10.

Adding half the divider (for proper rounding) does help:

```
uint32_t ema = 0;
const unsigned factor = 8; // 2^factor overall smoothing
const unsigned m = (0b1u << factor) - 1u;
const unsigned a = 0b1u << (factor - 1);
ema = (ema * m + adc[0] + a) >> factor;
```

Adding `a` halves the gap, but there's still a noticeable skew. Using `m` instead of `a` seems better but now the EMA average is slightly higher than it should be (visually comparing the result), though the difference is very small. Intuitively adding `m` seems like a hack?

Is there a better way to get the average where it should be?

Comment: If the range of readings is so small, can't you just use a moving average?

Comment: Shouldn't `ema` be initialized with the first reading, not with 0?

Comment: @Atmo Yes, but over time it makes no difference so it wasn't relevant to the question. The full code (doing multiple channels using a fold expression) has that but looks as ugly as a fold expression can be. To Simon: That's just one example value that was stable enough to give some concrete details and show how the average is even outside of the range of original values. Other readings vary more.

Comment: Yes but you need hundreds if not thousands of readings. Anyway, that one is just a small adjustment... I suppose you cannot change `ema`'s type to be `double` (or `float` if it makes calculation faster)?

Comment: Maybe take a square mean root moving average to flatten out noisy spikes? Something like y = sum{i = 1 to n} isqrt(xi << 16), smravg = ((y/n)^2) >> 16.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the code throws away the fractional portion of `ema`. `ema` needs to be a [fixed-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) so that some of the fractional bits are retained.

Comment: Stefan, that's an interesting question, but since it is conceptual in large part, it might be better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Stefan Curious, why `0b1u` and not `1u`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: "oh, I need 1 bit" -> `0b1`. One coffee later: "Wait, that needs to be unsigned, for some reason binary literals are signed" -> adds `u`. `1u` would've been better in hindsight.

Comment: Integer multiplication and division is 100% accurate unless there is an overflow. Your question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: @user207421 according to you 5 / 2 = 2 is 100% accurate? That doesn't make any sense, not sure what you're trying to add here?

Answer (score 2):

I question how you get `1690` with this implementation and only values from `1700` to `1704`. A [mathematical analysis of your implementation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e3zpxncw6r) caps the mean to 1449.

In order to get past this cap, input values would need to be higher than `1704`, [around `1945`](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b1ypmnns7q).

Anyway, in order to get your mean to converge toward the actual mean, you need to store fractional values. The simplest idea is to scale everything by 256 (or `2`<sup>`factor`</sup>), and divide by that amount when accessing the actual mean:

```
template<unsigned factor = 8u>
struct mean_t
{
    auto constexpr static alpha = (1u << factor) - 1u;
    unsigned _scaled_mean = 0u;
    
    unsigned value() const { return _scaled_mean >> factor; }
    
    constexpr mean_t& operator<<(unsigned datapoint)
    {
        unsigned const scaled_datapoint = datapoint << factor;
        _scaled_mean = (_scaled_mean * alpha + scaled_datapoint) >> factor;
        return *this;
    }
};

// Usage:
unsigned compute()
{
    mean_t mean;
    for (auto const datapoint : data) {
        mean << datapoint;
    }
    return mean.value(); // converges toward 1701 with values in 1700--1704;
}
```

[Full demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Yq8cxWbnK)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a "low pass filter" as it will elimiate high frequency changes from your data stream. The simplest is a running average.

```
int runningAverage(int *sum, int factor, int val)
{
    int lsum = *sum;
    if(lsum == INT_MIN) lsum = val << factor;
    else { lsum -= lsum >> factor; lsum += val;}

    *sum = lsum;
    return lsum >> factor;
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum = INT_MIN;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int datap = 0; datap < 500;datap++)
    {   
        int reading = 1700 + rand() % 5;
        printf("%d%s", runningAverage(&sum, 3, reading), (datap + 1) % 20 ? " " : "\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/98cae6Pn5

Comment: `lsum >> factor` biases the average down by 0.5 so we still have the "always downward" issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep the state (sum) of the prior readings.
  This helps keep track of the fractional parts otherwise lost with `(ema * m + adc[0]) >> factor`.
- Use a *rounded* division to not bias the readings downward.

```
unsigned smoothed_adc(unsigned new_reading) {
  static bool first_time = true;
  static uint32_t sum = 0;
  const unsigned factor = 8;
  const uint32_t two_power_factor = ((uint32_t)1 << factor);
  const uint32_t two_power_factor_half = two_power_factor/2;

  if (first_time) {
    first_time = false;
    sum = adc*two_power_factor;
  } else {
    sum += adc;
  }
  // Add 1/2 before division.
  adc = (sum + two_power_factor_half) >> factor;
  sum -= adc;
  return adc;
}
```

I'd used `#define` instead for `factor, two_power...` to insure no run-time math.

---

**Deeper**

I'd expect a set of readings with many 1700 and a few 1701 to not always report a smoothed reading of 1700, but a 1701 now and then.  By subtracting from the `sum` the reported value, `sum` accumulates differences between  original `adc` and reported `adc`.

Comment: He wants many channels. `static` in function makes it only single channel and non-reentrant.

Comment: @gulpr True, yet easy enough for a coder to pass in the state: `bool first_time, uint32_t sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add fixed point arithmetics to your code. I see it like this (both standard ring FIFO and exponential sliding averages):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint32_t savg(uint32_t x,bool init=false)       // ring FIFO
    {
    // log2(x)+s <= 32
    // creates constant phase shift equal to 2^(s-1) samples
    // amlitude is dampened with rising frequency(x)
    const  uint32_t s=5;        // smothing bits
    const  uint32_t m=1<<s;     // smothing size
    static uint32_t a=0;        // actual sliding average sum
    static uint32_t FIFO[m],a0=0;// FIFO
    if (init)
        {
        for (a0=0;a0<m;a0++) FIFO[a0]=x;
        a=x<<s; a0=0;
        }
    a-=FIFO[a0]; a+=x; FIFO[a0]=x;
    a0++; a0&=m-1;
    // return raw integer (no fixed point)
//  return (a            )>>s;  // floor
    return (a+( 1<<(s-1)))>>s;  // round
//  return (a+((1<<s)-1)))>>s;  // ceil
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint32_t savg_exp(uint32_t x,bool init=false)   // exponential
    {
    // log2(x)+f+s <= 32
    // creates non linear phase shift depending on s,frequency(x)
    // amlitude is dampened with rising frequency(x)
    // adds variable offset (it disipates for periodic signals after multiple periods)
    const  uint32_t f=8;        // fixed point bits
    const  uint32_t s=5;        // smothing bits
    static uint32_t a=0;        // actual sliding average in fixed point
    if (init) a=x<<f;
    a=(((a<<s)-a)+(x<<f))>>s;
    // return raw integer (no fixed point)
//  return (a            )>>f;  // floor
    return (a+( 1<<(f-1)))>>f;  // round
//  return (a+((1<<f)-1 ))>>f;  // ceil
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

just make sure that sum of `bits_of(x)+s+f<=32` otherwise you overflow. Also as suggested in comments the `a` should be initialized with either first data value or some default value so just run the filter with init true the first time otherwise the start will be biased by the zero (however even such init introduce bias but it should be smaller). Beware both methods have its quirks they are noted in comments at each function start.

Here example results for sin wave + some random noise where grayish is the input data and blue averaged one.

**(f=8, s=5):**

[image: exmaple s=5]

**(f=8, s=6):**

[image: exmaple s=6]

**(f=8, s=7):**

[image: exmaple s=7]

Here comparison of exponential (blue) and FIFO (red) sliding avg both with phase shift correction:

[image: comparison FIFO vs. exp both s=5]

If you look closely exponential (blue) has offset in first ~5 periods until it dissipates. Also as you can see exponential savg is dampening much more with the same `s` bitwidth ...

I dislike the fact that phase shift is changing with signal frequency for exponential savg, that is why I use FIFO based savg instead at the cost of needed memory...